# Каждые 7 очков ловкости увеличивают броню на 1

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть значение agility - ловкость, надо чтоб за каждое 7-ое очко ловкости прибавлялось 1 очко к защите - defense

```
if (agility % 7 == 0)
{
        defense += 1;
}
```

пробовал так выводит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
defense = agility / 7;
```

Comment: а если у меня 22?

Comment: @SashaDomase: Будет `defense == 3`.

Comment: нет, спасибо большое всё работает:)

Comment: @SashaDomase: вот и хорошо! Пожалуйста!

Comment: не могли бы помочь ещё в кое-чём?

Comment: @SashaDomase: Попробую :) Может быть, лучше задать отдельным вопросом?

Comment: Добавил http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/486813/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0

Comment: @SashaDomase: Нет, с таким я не сталкивался. Но думаю, другие участники что-нибудь скажут по теме.